# Using SUVAT equations of kinematics when using an accelerating frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, friction, collision

I have a conceptual question arising from the following problem, which relates to the application of the *constant translational acceleration in a straight line [(SUVAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Constant_translational_acceleration_in_a_straight_line)* equations of kinematics of a mass point.

> A bullet of mass $m$ is ﬁred horizontally with speed u into a wooden block of mass $M$ at rest on a horizontal surface. The coefficient of friction between the block and the surface is $\mu$. While the bullet is moving through the block, it experiences a constant force of resistance to its motion of magnitude $R$, where $R > (M+m)\mu g$. The bullet moves horizontally in the block and does not emerge from the other side of the block.
>
> (i) Show that the magnitude of the deceleration a of the bullet relative to the block while the bullet is moving through the block is given by

$$a=\frac{R}{m}+\frac{R-(M+m)\mu g}{M} \tag{1}.$$

This part of the problem is easy to solve using the [SUVAT equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Constant_translational_acceleration_in_a_straight_line). However, it is the second part of the problem that is puzzling me. This part is as follows.

> (ii)  Show that the common speed of the block and bullet when the bullet stops moving through the block, which is denoted by $v$, satisﬁes 
>   $$av=\frac{Ru-(M+m)\mu gu}{M} \tag{2}.$$

Let us see the two conflicting solutions which I worked out for this part of the problem. The speed $v$ can be calculated using the fact that the final speed of the bullet relative to the accelerating block is zero, as $$0=u-at_c \tag{3},$$
since $u$ would be same for both the stationary frame and the accelerating-block frame, and $t_c$ denotes the time when $v$ is reached. Now consider the acceleration of the block (of mass $M$) in the stationary horizontal surface frame $S$ given by $$a_{MS}=\frac{R-(M+m)g\mu}{M} \tag{4}.$$ The speed $u$ is then given by
$$v=v_{MS}=(a_{MS})(t_c)=\left(\frac{R-(M+m)g\mu}{M}\right) \left(\frac{u}{a}\right) \tag{5}.$$
On the other hand, if we consider the acceleration of the bullet (of mass $m$) relative to the stationary surface frame $S$, applying the SUVAT again yields $$v = v_{mS}=u-a_{mS}t_c \tag{6},$$ thus implying that, $$v=u-\left(\frac{R}{m} \right) \left(\frac{u}{a}\right) \tag{7},$$ which does not seem to co-incide with the previously calculated solution.

Why is it that I get a different answer when considering $a_{mS}$ alone and what conceptual errors are present in my work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excellent kinematics and dynamics question on the basic application of Newton's laws of motion.

The solution presented to both problems in the question is accurate. The question pertains to an alternate solution to the second problem, which evokes the question of whether the alternate solution is consistent with the prior analysis. Consider the two solutions $v = \frac{R - \mu (m + M) g}{M} \cdot \frac{u}{a}$ and $v = u - \frac{R}{m} \cdot \frac{u}{a}$. Setting the right hand sides of both solutions to be equal results in the equation $$a - \frac{R}{m} = \frac{R - \mu (m + M) g}{M},$$ which implies by doing some algebra, including some relative acceleration manipulations, that, $$M(a -\frac{R}{m}) = M(-a_{mM} + a_{mS}) \\
= M a_{MS} = R - \mu (m + M) g,$$
where we denote by $a_{mM} := - a < 0$, $a_{mS}$ and $a_{MS}$ the relative accelerations of the bullet w.r.t. the block, the bullet w.r.t. the stationary surface and the block w.r.t. the stationary surface, respectively. The last equation is consistent with our analysis.  In other words, given these two solutions which were arrived at by applying kinematics and Newton's dynamics equations, equating them yields the consistent Newton's second law of motion for the block.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does this imply that for the alternate solution to make sense, it does not have to be identically equal to the first solution? (or are they in fact identically equal to each other but this can only be shown after some more tedious rearrangements)?

Comment: The two solutions are identical. In that, you can start with the right hand side $\frac{u}{a} (a - \frac{R}{m})$ of the second solution, substitute the term $a - \frac{R}{m}$ as $\frac{R - \mu(m + M)g}{M}$ and obtain the first solution, to convince yourself that they are the same solution. Note that in doing so, you would have used the equation resulting from the application of Newton's second law of motion to the block.